# How to return variable from this function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to update the variable test to the result of the database collection that I queried.

```
var test;

db.collection('locale').find().toArray(function(err,results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't `db.collection('locale').find()` return something?

Comment: it returns a promise bro

Comment: If I understand your problem, you can't access to the test varibale inside your db callback. So you can define a variable `var _this = this`, add test to this and call it inside the callback, `_this.test = results`

Comment: Promise { <pending> }

Comment: @AntoineAmara Yes

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the `results` value from function callback to `test` variable. You can then iterate results array to get the values.

```
var test;

db.collection('locale').find().toArray(function(err,results){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);

    else {
        console.log(results);
        test = results;

        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            //process the results
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it returns undefined..

Comment: Are you sure you are entering the collection name correctly...??

Comment: And console.log the error also, if there's one...

Comment: it retunrs the result but what I want to do is return it as a callback or variable . So i can update the test variable which is no in the function db.collection

Comment: Actually it is returning as callback so if you need to use your test variable, you need to do that inside the callback function only. That's because it's a part of asynchronous code.

Comment: You could have done that if the call was a synchrounous one. 

In that case some method like `var test = db.collection('locale').find().toArraySync();`  would have helped you. 

But there's nothing like that.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the best way to do that.. if you want to return response as json you have to add `send()` or `render()` inside the callback function.

you are trying to work around asynchronous feature. why?

i think you are using nodejs. right? and you want to do some synchronous query. use this [Mongo Sync](https://npmjs.org/package/mongo-sync)

```
var Server = require("mongo-sync").Server;
var server = new Server('127.0.0.1');
var result = server.db("testdb").getCollection("testCollection").find().toArray();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

First, you can use ES6/2015 to have a better variables scope, so you have to write your code this way:

```
let test;

db.collection('locale').find().toArray((err,results) => {
    console.log(results);
    // it Work
    test = results
});
```

Secondly, you can create an _this variable:

```
var _this = this;
var test;

db.collection('locale').find().toArray(function(err,results){
    console.log(results);
     // it Work too
    _this.test = results;
});
```

In my opinion, the first case with ES6 is a better way and it is more readable.